# find uniq string from column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in DB which has two column `ID` and `DATA`

```
 ID   |  DATA                                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1    |  Day by day ocean level is increasing because of global warming level  
 2    |  Modern email operates across the Internet or other computer networks
```

**Note:** `level` is repeated word in `row 1`, I want only one time.

Here I want Unique word from `DATA` column just like below:

**Required Output:**

```
 Day by ocean level is increasing because of global warming

 Modern email operates across the Internet or other computer networks
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How to decide position to which duplicate words should be merged?

Comment: So, 'Day' and 'day' are two words?

Comment: ohh so sorry 'day' have to be only time.

Comment: its dynamic Parmod i don't know how to find the position of duplicate word

Comment: you could tokenize and insert each word to a temporary table to make them unique, apply index on word in new temporary table. [this](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/) will help you.

Comment: Thanx for Your valuable comment!! but i a mnew to DB side and i don't  know about indexing

Comment: @aashish_soni sorry i missed a word in my comment, by index i meant a unique index, this way when you insert all of your words to this temporary table duplicates will be ignored and you'll get unique words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, can you use `PHP`. And not sure this approach is preferable for you. Whatever it is this is a solution..

Retrieve the `data` using the `sql query` and treat the `data` using `PHP` like this

```
$text ="Day by day ocean level is increasing because of global warming level";
$str = implode(' ',array_unique(explode(' ', strtolower($text))));
echo ucfirst($str);
```

**Result:**

```
Day by ocean level is increasing because of global warming
```